# Serlvet Init breaks when adding HttpServletResponse interface?

Tags: java, servlets

All,

In my Init() function for my servlet I want to be able to send back XML responses for situations such as

1. DB connection failed
2. Query file could not be opened

So I decided to add the HttpServletResponse interface class as an argument to init()

```
    /**
 * Open the connection here this method only happens once when the servlet is initialised by the Web Server for the first time it will persist until the Web Server is shut down
 **/
public void init(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        db = new DatabaseLogic();
        String debug = getServletContext().getInitParameter("debug");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log(getServletInfo());
        log("Failed to open a connection to the database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // retrieve all queries from xml from classpath
    queries = new Properties();
    try
    {
        // note : be wary of forward slash when added to path
        path = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF") + "/";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/gari_queries.xml"));
        try
        {
            queries.loadFromXML(fis);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            setErrorResponse("1", "The GARI Service could not parse the SQL file, please check the syntax.", response);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fis.close();
        db.openDatabase();
    }
    catch (IOException io)
    {
        // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        setErrorResponse("1", "The GARI Service could not find/load the SQL file.", response);
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        setErrorResponse("1", "The GARI Service could not open a connection to the Archive Database.", response);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (NamingException e)
    {
        // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        setErrorResponse("1", "The GARI Service could not find/load the Server's JDBC pool.", response);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

However after doing so, it has broken my init() function, all my objects such are not initalised.

Why is it breaking?

Why can doGet accept this interface but other functions can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stacker is right..

```
public void init() throws ServletException
```

you can throw exception..servlet will not be placed in service.. and handle use web.xml and jsp to send meaning full response..

Answer (score 1):

The [init method](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig)) is part of the interface [Servlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) it takes only one parameter [ServletConfig](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html).

It is used to initialize the services provided by the servlet and won't be called for a each request as doGet or doPost would.

The servlet container only knows the methods provided by the interface and can't call any other methods having different signatures. Therefore you can't add HttpServletRequest or  HttpServletResponse as a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to know that this is a dangerous and unstable thing to do.

The "init" method is called once, when the servlet is loaded. The "doGet" method might potentially be called many hundreds or thousands of times over a period of weeks, months or years.

Almost all databases will "time out" and disconnect open connections if they are left open for too long. If you only open a connection in "init" it may even "time out" before you get to use it. This also implies that you have no way of re-opening a closed connection without reloading the servlet.

All in all, opening a database connection is "init" is a bad thing to do. A much better solution is to use one of the many implementations of a "connection pool". Instead of opening a connection in "init" you create a connection pool. That connection pool is then available whenever your servlets needs a database connection. Your software asks the pool for a connection, and the pool either hands over an existing open connection, opens a new one for you, or reopens one that has been closed by the database. Either way, your software should not need to worry about it.

I realize that this is not directly answering your question, but trying to work out what is wrong with your current approach might actually be wasted time for you.

Comment: I am using a connection pool